# linear ODE problem

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

> A substance evaporates at a rate proportional to the exposed surface. If a spherical mothball of radius  $\frac{1}{2}$ cm has radius $0.4$ cm after $6$ months, how long will it take:
>
> 1. For the radius to be  $\frac{1}{4}$ cm?
> 2. For the volume of the mothball to be half of what it was originally?

So I understand the radius of the sphere gets smaller as the time goes by.

$$\frac{dV}{dt}=4\pi (r-t)^2$$

I came to this, but it does not seems to right

Comment: Hint: shouldn't it be $-4\pi r^2$, where $r=r(t)$ is a function of time?

Comment: Start by $
\frac{dV_t}{dt}=-C4\pi(r_t)^2
$, where $V_t$ is the volume, $r_t$ is the radius after time $t$, and $C$ is the (unknown!) proportionality constant. Expressing $r$ in terms of $V$ and substituting the known values at time $0$ and $6$ month should get you there.

Comment: @mge you forgot the square over $r$.

Comment: @mge but I will get a square root

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:

Not caring about multiplicative constants,

$$\frac{dV}{dt}=\frac{dr^3}{dt}=-Kr^2,$$

i.e.

$$\frac{dr}{dt}=-K.$$

The radius decreases linearly.

Comment: why do $\frac{dV}{dt}=\frac{dr^3}{dt}$?

Comment: Because $V=r^3$, maybe.

Comment: sorry, thought about the area

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{d}{dt}(\frac43\pi r^3) = -4k\pi r^2, $$
$$3r^2\frac43\pi \frac{dr}{dt} = -4k\pi r^2,$$ 
$$\frac{dr}{dt} = -k $$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).